# Consider retagging version specific [minecraft] questions to [minecraft-0.12]

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft, game-versions

We currently have [42 questions about Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft). Some of those can be expected to still be valid in the final release (examples: [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/can-i-load-and-save-my-minecraft-maps-to-my-dropbox), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/how-can-i-make-a-skeleton-shoot-a-creeper), [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8853/how-do-you-create-a-waterfall-elevator), [4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9345/looking-for-a-game-similar-to-minecraft-that-allows-scripting)), while others are more or less clearly version-specific (examples: [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9047/how-do-i-set-up-a-minecart-booster), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/how-can-i-fix-my-graphical-problem-in-minecraft), [3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9273/smp-alpha-water-not-transferable), [4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9047/how-do-i-set-up-a-minecart-booster)).

We should consider retagging the more likely to be version-specific problems to a tag that includes the version number, or at least using our [patch "policy"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches) on them.

Comment: Shouldn't the questions have both, the minecraft tag and a version specific one? On SO I sometimes miss questions that have only a version specific tag applied, while I have only the main, version-independent tag favorited.

Comment: One cleanup I think needs to be done is clarifying "beta 1.x" vs "release 1.x" - we're at release 1.1 now, and likely to hit 1.3 or 1.4 by the end of this year. It'll be confusing to read "as of 1.4" and have to guess beta vs release. It also couldn't hurt to go through old questions and update the answers as of release 1.0/1.1. And maybe change "will be added in 1.8" to "was added in 1.8"... I'm going to end up on a cleanup crusade aren't I?

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me the patch policy you linked will be adequate, though I confess ignorance about this specific game.

We *do* have enough 2k+ users who play this game, so I guess they should edit these questions/answers. Though it's always better if the original poster updates the post, I think that it's very appropriate to edit a notification in when they present obsolete information.

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to revive this question. ***Please, comment, don't silently down-vote.***

I think Minecraft-related questions on Gaming.SE shouldn't be updated to the latest release, at least the question itself and the accepted answer. Some people like me will sit on 1.0.0 for some time, as it was for 1.8.1 earlier (since mods like Industrial Craft get ported very slowly, around one month after release), and some day they will decide to check one of their favorite questions, and won't find the answer they were looking for.

The easiest solution would be to start every answer with the relevant version of Minecraft, like so:

> **1.8.1 BETA**
>
> *No*, you can't enchant your tools, this version of Minecraft doesn't have that functionality.

And a couple of months later, new answer, or addition to the original one, not replacement:

> **1.0.0**
>
> *Yes*, you can get XP by killing some mobs and then enchant any tool on the enchantment table.

Even if the current answer doesn't seem to ever get outdated (like "Can I swim up in the vertical stream of water? - Yes, you can!"), it's a good idea to put the current version at the beginning. Who knows, maybe in two years, in Minecraft 4.0, it won't be true?

Another solution - tags, but that will make the whole question version-specific, what is less universal, than the previous one.

And we can't use the "patch policy" here, because I know lot's of people using [MCNostalgia](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/800346-tool-mcnostalgia-201/), since some adventure/redstone-creation maps aren't compatible with newer versions, or, perhaps, they just want to feel nostalgia, as the tool name suggests (in some versions the terrain-generator could create crazy-looking landscapes, which are impossible now, like big floating islands in the air). Moreover, patches are supposed to be bug-fixes and obvious improvements, while Minecraft sometimes makes a step back, like disabling snow-biome, messing up the lighting or excluding a mob (like the Giant).

What do you think?

P.S. Should I make a separate question out of this?

Comment: Big floating islands in the air are far from impossible.  I got one in my 1.0 world.

Comment: That was just an example, I think you will agree that they give different results.