# Why are the question and my answer downvoted?

Tags: support

I have had a question in my head similar to [this one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/consider-retagging-version-specific-minecraft-questions-to-minecraft-0-12), and have decided to consolidate everything in one place, and answered it with my own proposals. It got downvoted by several people, for no obvious reason. Where am I wrong? Is there more popular duplicate question? Or I can't discuss this subject? Please, help me out here.

Answer (score 7):

Downvotes have a slightly different meaning on meta.  Since there is no reputation involved, they are generally used to indicate "I disagree".  So if you ask a question about what should be done, and someone thinks nothing should be done, they might downvote.  Or if you propose an answer, even if it is very well thought out and explained, someone might downvote if they disagree.  Don't worry too much about it, it doesn't hurt you at all, and people don't tend to pay much attention to vote counts on meta.

Comment: Well, I've noticed that my reputation never went down, but I'm still concerned about this. Why no one explains, why they disagree?

Comment: I wouldn't trust you though. One of your meta questions has a score of -4! :O

Comment: @Ulla See, I'm speaking from experience.  Although that one is apparently caused by an even stranger phenomenon of downvoting questions that talk about downvoting.