# Update old answers according to patch notes for unreleased patch

Tags: discussion

The announced [Civilization 5 December patch](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?99880-December-Patch-Full-Change-List) will change quite a lot of gameplay elements and it will invalidate some old answers on this site.

The changes will render some answers factually incorrect, an example is the [question about buying courthouses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/in-civ5-is-it-possible-to-buy-a-courthouse) or the [question about research overflow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10596/production-and-research-overflow-in-civilization-5).

Should we edit the answers to those questions immediately with a note on the behaviour after the upcoming patch? Or should we wait until it is officially released?

Should the old, incorrect answer remain (side-by-side with an updated answer) after the patch is released or should we consistently remove any outdated information? In this case it is a Steam game where almost everyone is playing the latest patch automatically, but with offline mode it is still possible to play older versions. Removing the outdated part would tidy up the question and the old answer is still available in the revision history.

Comment: Related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the accepted answer in the [related question Grace linked](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches): Update answers that have become outdated and close questions which are no longer applicable as too localized *once the patch is released*.

Comment: Agreed - let's first wait until the new version is released.

Comment: Do you think we should verify the changes in the patch ourselves, or should we just trust the official patch notes to be accurate?

Comment: @Fabian Trust the patch notes to be accurate and fix if shown inaccuracies. We've trusted the patch notes for other answers for other games and there's no reason Civ V should be different.