# Should questions be flagged as a duplicate to an out of date question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280088/cant-click-on-pokemon-in-the-nearby-menu-and-no-footseps-showing-for-distance) about the 'Nearby' section of Pokémon Go addresses the current state functionality (no pawprints, Pokémon are not clickable to determine direction). It was suggested as a duplicate of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275591/why-do-the-pokemon-always-have-three-pawprints), which details the issues from the previous update with the 'Nearby' section (all Pokémon show as 3 pawprints away).

I considered commenting on the answer of the 'previous version' question to say that the answer was out of date, in hopes of an edit... but it does technically answer the question, which I suppose is also now out of date. After reading a couple of meta posts about updating old questions/answers (see below), I'm still not sure what the right way to address this is.

[How should we deal with out of date questions/answers?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/how-should-we-deal-with-out-of-date-questions-answers)

[Updating an out of date answer versus keeping author intent](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/updating-an-out-of-date-answer-versus-keeping-author-intent)

I've also seen meta posts (that I can't find right now, of course... I believe it addressed the Diablo 3 Auction House) about closing questions for past versions of games, as they they probably don't help anybody since that version of the game isn't playable anymore.

1. Should the first question about the "three step glitch" be closed or updated, since it is based on an older version of the game, and users shouldn't be experiencing it anymore?
2. If not... should the newer question truly be considered a duplicate of the first? I'm not sure marking the new question as a duplicate will answer or help the asker, since that isn't the same issue he is experiencing.

Comment: Tracking is borked.  Do we *seriously* need more than one question about the various symptoms that crop up because of that?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/duplicate-questions-a-new-look)

Comment: @Frank Tracking is *very* borked. I don't think we need more than one question, either. However, I honestly didn't know what the feeling was on if we should close the first question, since it is now for a past, unplayable version, or how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It has not been marked as a dupe, one person has cast a vote. Sometimes people get it wrong, which is why 5 votes are required. (In my opinion, these are different questions, albeit with similarish answers)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated my question title to be more correct. You're right, it was only flagged, not marked, as a dupe. I agree with @Frank though, that we don't need two of these questions floating around, which led to my greater question... does the first one have any right being open, since it answers an out of date, no longer playable version of the game?

Answer (score 0):

They are not duplicates, though they are related. One asks about a bug in a feature, the other about a change in a feature from a new update. They are different, but related problems.