# Are questions asking for updated info duplicates?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

In reference to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/318453/145980)... The OP of that question more or less admits that they know that their question is a duplicate. However, they also claim that all the answers in the question are out of date due to Minecraft's new launcher. Therefore, they created this new question asking for updated info.

Now, I was under the impression that there are better ways of asking for updated info in a question that has been asked in the past. Bounties are the primary method of reviving an old question, but edits could also potentially help out with that niche. However, I checked Meta for some confirmation and was not able to find a satisfactory (for me) resolution.

In the meta discussion, [Handling dupes asking for updated info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12611/145980), the comments seem to indicate that a bounty/edit should have been made. But then the only actual answer that says this is downvoted, and the two related questions are both still open.

There are [even](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10765/145980) [more](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1527/145980) [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/946/145980) [discussions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1339/145980) where it's suggested to update answers on the existing question if the answers go out of date, but none of these handle duplicates. So, what do we do with duplicates that are asking for updated info? Close them as duplicates? Close the old question as a duplicate of the new? Leave them both alone? I think an official stance would be helpful for clarifying the rules.

Comment: More to the point, the asker made no attempt to even see if the answers were out of date before asking. There was no issue with the old question; the answers worked fine. Dupe.

Comment: I think before we even consider this, we need to know if the update actually broke the old stuff. If the old answers still work, dupe no question, but I think what you're really trying to ask here is "what do we do when things have changed and old answers don't work with updated things" which...isn't really the case for the linked question, if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: Those answers are (in my opinion) quite clearly different.  Yes, the steps in both cases are _similar_; but there are some differences.  The launcher seems to require a separate move for itself now.  But most importantly the _entire_ interface is different where you change the directory.  The old launcher required you to pick "edit profile", the new one is under "launch options".  I'm sure to many of us, it's pretty easy to fiddle around the menu until we find it.  Not everyone is good at finding detailed settings though.  I think it's a hyperbole to say the other answer is the same.

Comment: The other answer _almost_ worked; but it referenced several things that have since changed; making it potentially confusing to someone with minimal computer experience.

Comment: @JMac When closing questions as duplicates, you don't look at the answers. You look at the question. The two questions are very clearly the same, with the sole exception being the new one asking for an updated answer. Whether the answers are the same is irrelevant.

Comment: @JMac Also, there's more than 1 answer on the older question. I don't play Minecraft anymore so I can't test it myself, but those answers look like they should work even on the new launcher, since it involves using the operating system to work around file relocations.

Comment: @MageXy This is in reference to the other two comments here; which both highly suggest that the answers to both questions are identical.  I agree that this isn't central to the real question here, but I also do think it's a really helpful answer.  The main interface seems to have changed a lot of the terms.  As far as the other answers go; one is just a command line to make the computer adjust.  That one is universal and good.  The other one seems to involve a more complicated process of creating batches etc.  Either way, those both seem pretty complicated for a non-technical user.

Comment: I honestly do think we need some sort of system in place to deal with these types of questions.  It's a big problem here because of how much games can update.  I think Timmy's answer should be incorporated into the other one, or something similar in this case; because ultimately, it's the built-in solution to the problem, and the "most correct" way to deal with it.

Comment: Related meta on SuperUser: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6240/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling dupes asking for updated info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/handling-dupes-asking-for-updated-info)

Answer (score 2):

We should clearly not just update old answers with new info: someone might still be interested in the old version of Minecraft, and the one adding new info doesn't get much reputation for that. Stuff gets too messy this way.

I think, it is good if not best to add another answer to the old question, saying that "The answer by user B is no longer up to date since version x.y.z., you should now use these steps: (Steps)". The answer by user B could then be edited with a line added in the top, saying something like "This answer is no longer up to date since version x.y.z., for an up to date info look at the answer by user A".

Even if the old answer is accepted and/or has the highest score, the "no longer up to date" disclaimer, written in bold, would redirect any newcomers to the new info and preserve the old stuff.

If this new answer also goes outdated, we change all of the existing ones to note which of them goes for which version and add a link to an up to date one. Same goes for questions that have 9001 no longer related answers; they get edited with a note.

If no new answer is available yet, one can just add a note "this answer is no longer up to date since version x.y.z.", possibly explaining it in the edit text, possibly in the edit description. This will also poke the answer to the front page, potentially attracting new answers. +2 rep per edit would be a small bonus for those who edit and attract attention to answers that a are no longer up to date and can potentially mislead, and those who write new answers get rep from upvotes, bounties might be used if someone wants more attention to those questions.

It should only be done if the old question can still host the new answer, if we can safely add a new one so it still answers the question and the latter doesn't need significant edits.

It should also only be done if the old info could potentially have a value besides historical significancy. For example, one may still launch an old version of Minecraft, even if it is unsupported, and benefit from an answer about an old version. But if an answer has an old price of TF2 items at public marketplace, it might be interesting to see it in the edit history, but no longer could you actually buy items for those prices, so we can just edit the old answer and update the prices.

The only potential problem I see: some questions could theoretically get a huge number of no longer related answers, the related onces being stuck in the bottom.

Comment: So if I have a better answer, I should both a) post my better answer, and b) mark the currently-accepted answer as "no longer useful"? It's pretty unlikely that the original answerer will come back and edit their own question. This two-step process sounds mostly like me promoting my own answer.

Comment: @PaulMarshall Exactly! If you see an old questions where all answers are outdated, you: 1) Add your new answer (if you have one). This pokes the question to the front page already. 2) You edit all other answers that are no longer related with a note and a link to your answer. If you don't have an answer, you just mark answers that are no longer related.

Comment: You are free to post your own answer.  Do *not* post a link to it on the other answers, however; that can be seen as self promotion.  Even editing the others to denote they're outdated, while the intent is good, can be seen as vandalism.  Your best bet is to just post your own answer.

Comment: This is a good answer, but *what* should we do with the new questions? I don't see anything suggesting "we should treat them as new question" or "still close them as dupe of the old question" or something like that. This answer is better posted in https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/handling-dupes-asking-for-updated-info instead

Answer (score -1):

This is a good question.   How to handle outdated information in general.

The site is here to answer questions.  The site is filled with a lot of outdated answers.  Minecraft has lots of users who like to play old versions so I think outdated answers should be left, but edited with a note of last functioning version.

The problem I see with the current system:

From the person who needs a current answer.  Lets say I find my exact question only it was asked by someone 3 years ago.  All the answers no longer function.  What do I do?  Do I set a bounty and hope someone with an answer realizes that is why there is a bounty?  Maybe include a comment that asks for updated information?  Is asking for updated information to someone else's question in a comment encouraged?  What if I am new here and have no reputation to give?  Why do I have to offer up reputation to get an updated answer because someone asked my question a long time ago?

From the side of people answering questions.  I don't see a whole lot of people digging through very old questions and answering with updated answers.  They don't get up votes if they do.  I am here to help people find their answers.  I don't care about reputation so I do update old questions for no reason.  Here is an [example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317879/186522) answer with no up votes (currently).  A lot of people do care about reputation and that is their incentive to do anything here.

This is a system where someone seeking an answer is going to find a lot of outdated answers and people answering have no incentive to update those old questions.  If someone then asks a same question, seeking new information, we are marking it as duplicate of a question with answers that don't work.  I would imagine there are several users who see [duplicate] and don't even look at the question.

I think there should be a system that points new questions to old questions and incentivizes updating old information while leaving and noting outdated information rather then allowing the same question to be asked multiple times.

Currently, in the instances I have seen like this, I give an updated answer to the original question and comment on the duplicate question so the OP of the duplicate can get an answer.