# What happens to outdated answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I checked this [question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/outdated-answers-due-to-patches) answered by badp. The answer on that was less than satisfactory. :-)

I just saw a bounty from badp on [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/how-does-animal-spawning-work). The reason was the current answers were out of date.

How does one know to revise their answer on a question? Do they get informed via the red Inbox notification? What happens if no one revises their answers to a question? Can we ask the same question again or will it get closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if someone gets notified if there's a bounty placed on a question they answered, but there is something you can do: leave a comment on the answer.  If you think their answer can be updated, say something like "Hey, would you consider updating your answer?"  It's as simple as that.

Comment: Or if it's a totally minor change like "in version 2.0 this costs $40 instead of 30" you can just edit in an update if you know what needs fixing. Also you're not notified of bounties as an answerer.

Comment: @desaivv: Asking again will be [closed as duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89684/#comment123496_89684).  Also, that ME lore question is a bad example, as the answer has been known since ME2 (and because I personally think it's a poor question).  Leviathan just provided the full in-universe explanation.  I thought there was talk about automatically placing a banner on questions that haven't had activity since a patch, but I can't seem to find that discussion.